# Version 28 is the latest version of the legacy support

Tags: android-studio

Hello iam trying to add this library :compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0\n'
but getting error: Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help with this: Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX...

any fix?

Comment: Just migrate your project to android x using the hint above `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX` as support libraries are deprecated now, also don't use the deprecated `compile` directive and replace it with `implementation`

Comment: Hello thanks for always trying to help me first , Second i migrated to AndroidX but still getting same error however error goes when i add this before the library  " //noinspection GradleCompatible" what do you think ?

Comment: This was the fix : implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0' & implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' &  implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

Comment: Hello FoxAli, you can upgrade android studio, and get rid of that pain, the newer versions support only androidx when it comes to create new projects.

Comment: I am already using the latest android studio

Answer (score 0):

Bro its very simple just change
com.android.support:cardview-v7:(your targetsdkversion digits).0.0

instead of com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0...it will work

Answer (score 0):

Use the following dependencies instead of old ones in **gradle** scripts on **Module** level

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```